# Need jQuery to load html files one by one?

Tags: jquery

I have some Html files page1.html, page2.html, page3.html... and on click of next button I want to load this html file one by one. I need some jquery function for this please help me on this.

Comment: $.load() check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), like:

```
$("#someEle").load("first_file.html", function() {
   //done loading first
   $("#someEle").load("second_file.html", function() {
      //do loading second
   });
});
```

or

```
var defr = [];
defr.push($.get('first_file.html'));
defr.push($.get('second_file.html'));
$.when.apply($,defr).done(function(first_response,second_response){
    //all done, do something
});
```

or create an array of files, and load like:

```
function loadFiles() {
    var files = ['page1.html', 'page2.html'.....];
    if(files.length > 0) {
      $.get(files.shift(), function(response) {
          //do something with response
          loadFiles(); //until you have it in files array
      });
    }
}
//call the function
loadFiles();
```

Comment: I have one doubt what if I have more than 50 html files.and One more thing I am loading this page1.html file in div1,, page2.html in div2 like this way

Comment: Of course in production you have to deal with the `.fail()` part somehow too.

Comment: hi I had tried this but not working  like this                                     function loadFiles() {
 alert('load files');
        var files = ['index2.html', 'index.html'];
 alert('array')
        if(5 > 0) {
  $("#tabpage_1 div#" + id + "1").html(files.join());
          //do something with response
          loadFiles();
 }//until you have it in files array
      }